# jquery toggle between inputs

Tags: jquery

I need to find a way to switch between four text inputs.

Example Usage:

Input Names:

```
input1a
input1b
input2a
input2b
```

A user can only enter text in either inputs a or inputs b.

If user clicks on input1a then he can only enter text in input1a and input2a. Input1b and input2b will have their values deleted and faded (ie: text input turns into regular labels) and vice-versa.

A user can also toggle between inputs a and b.

Is there a jquery code that does this? any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious what the usage model for this is?

Comment: curiosity killed the cat ;) It's actually complicated score entries, I try to keep it as simple as I could.

Comment: all inputs are text or labels. By clicks, I mean if they click inside the text input or label. I hope that clears it a bit.

Comment: Sorry, by labels I mean disabling the text inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear on your html structure, but something like this seems to be what you describe:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', 'label', function() {
        if ($(this).next('input').hasClass('disabled')) {
            $('input').toggleClass('disabled').val('');
        }
    });
});
```

In this case, I am assuming you have labels, and the inputs are every other.  `.disabled` is simply a class which hides the inputs.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/bKW4Q/

You probably don't want to truly `disable` the inputs, because then they won't fire click events.  But, since you are clearing them, just make your disabled class gray them out:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/VWYpe/

This lets you click the inputs instead of the labels.

Comment: that's perfect...but how can I make the inputs clickable instead of the labels?

Comment: See edit.  You just gray out the inputs instead of making them hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class 'a' to all inputa elements and also add a class 'b' to all inputb.  If you do that you could do something like this.

```
$('.a').on('click', function() {
    $('.b').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.a').removeAttr('disabled');
});
$('.b').on('click', function() {
    $('.a').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.b').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can add classes to the inputs (`.a` and `.b`, for instance), you could write something like this:

```
var setActive = function(selector) {
  $('.a, .b').removeAttr('disabled');
  $(selector).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}

$('.a').click(function(){
  setActive('.a');
});

$('.b').click(function(){
  setActive('.a');
});
```

..you can adjust the selectors as needed to fit your situation, but you get the idea. This will not handle a click inside an already-active element very gracefully, but it should do what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot click on disabled inputs.  They won't fire a click handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Init
$('input').attr("disabled", "disabled");

// Bind click
$('label').click(function() {
    // Clear
    $('input').each(function() { $(this).val("").attr("disabled", "disabled"); });

    // Activate
    $(this).next('input').removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

**Sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/CZPbK/